# LINQ in C# to get Check In and Check Out Time for Employees

Tags: c#, linq

I have following collection and need results for each employee (EID) in per date per row for Check In and Check out. Can anyone please suggest the results in Console.WriteLine or in JSON grouped by Employee ID (EID)  ? Some of employees have been checked in and checked out but some are checked in and didnt check out.

```
List<StatusProcess> status = new List<StatusProcess>()
                {
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 1, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 08:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 1, StatusName = "CheckOut", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 10:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 2, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 08:10:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 3, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 10:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 4, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 08:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 5, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 08:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 2, StatusName = "CheckOut", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/2020 10:15:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 1, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/02/2020 08:04:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 1, StatusName = "CheckOut", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/02/2020 10:05:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 2, StatusName = "CheckIn", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/02/2020 08:00:00") },
                    new StatusProcess { EID = 2, StatusName = "CheckOut", Created = Convert.ToDateTime("08/02/2020 10:20:00") }
                };
```

Result I am expecting is like:

```
EID = 1, Date = 08/01/2020, CheckIn = 08:00:00, CheckOut = 10:00:00
EID = 1, Date = 08/02/2020, CheckIn = 08:04:00, CheckOut = 10:05:00
EID = 2, Date = 08/01/2020, CheckIn = 08:10:00, CheckOut = 10:15:00
EID = 2, Date = 08/02/2020, CheckIn = 08:00:00, CheckOut = 10:20:00
EID = 3, Date = 08/01/2020, CheckIn = 10:00:00, CheckOut = 
EID = 4, Date = 08/01/2020, CheckIn = 08:00:00, CheckOut = 
EID = 5, Date = 08/01/2020, CheckIn = 08:00:00, CheckOut =
```

Help in this regard would be appreciated please.

Comment: What have you tried to do to accomplish this? You say you want to use Linq. Have you looked up what Linq methods might be appropriate here? Tried to use them? What results did you get, and how did that differ from what you want?

Comment: If the result can be produced in JSON with EID Group then would be much helpful.

Comment: I have to use it to build an API in ASP.NET Core. I am getting results with one date but for multiple dates for one employee is making me stuck.

Comment: You haven't shown your work. It makes your question sound like you just want us to write your code for you, rather than help you with an existing problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This LINQ query should work:

```
var result = status
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.EID, s.Created.Date})
    .Select(gr => new 
    { 
        EID = gr.Key.EID,
        Date = gr.Key.Date,
        CheckIn = gr.Min(g => g.Created.TimeOfDay),
        CheckOut = gr.Max(g => g.Created.TimeOfDay)
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.EID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting Checkout for EID = 3,4,5 where they are not Checked Out.Can you advise how to make their Check Out EMPTY. Can we try some condition here against Check Out if this is not available in collection against the same date

Comment: You can use ternary operator for it:
 `CheckOut = gr.Count() > 1 ? gr.Max(g => g.Created.TimeOfDay) : default`. It gives you not empty but default value for `TimeSpan` which is 00:00:00

Comment: Can i get here EMPTY/NULL instead of 00:00:00

Comment: `CheckOut = gr.Count() > 1 ? (TimeSpan?)gr.Max(g => g.Created.TimeOfDay) : null`

Comment: Thank You...Worked...